# Elliptic curves, reduction map, $E_n$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be the elliptic curve and set $\phi: E(\mathbb{Q}_p) \rightarrow E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ to be the reduction morphism. Define $E_n := \{(x:y:z) \in \ker \phi | x/y \in p^n\mathbb{Z}_p\}$. I'm busy studying elliptic curves and found this exercise online: Show that $\forall n \geq 1$ and $(x:y:z) \in E_n$ it holds that $z/y \in p^{3n}\mathbb{Z}_p$. Now, I've been busy on this for a while now and this is what I've come up with:

In order to show that, I started with dividing the projective equation by $y^3$, which is allowed because of the fact that $(x:y:z) \in \ker \phi$: 
$$z/y= x^3/y^3 + axz^2/y^3 + bz^3/y^3.$$
Because $(x:y:z) \in E_n$, it follows that $x/y \in p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$ and because $(x:y:z) \in \ker \phi$, we have that $z/y \in p \mathbb{Z}_p$. Any ideas on how to continue?

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the equation you wrote down:
$$\frac{z}{y} = \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^3 + a\frac{x}{y}\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)^2+b\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)^3,$$
and for simplicity give names $X=z/y$ and $Z=z/y$, so you have:
$$Z = X^3+aXZ^2+bZ^3.$$
You are trying to find the $p$-adic valuation of $Z$, i.e., $\nu_p(Z)$, knowing that $\nu_p(X)\geq n$. You need to use two properties of $\nu_p$:

- $\nu_p(s+t)\geq \min \{\nu_p(s),\nu_p(t)\}$, with equality if $\nu_p(s)\neq \nu_p(t)$.
- $\nu_p(st)=\nu_p(s)+\nu_p(t)$.

We shall use these two properties to show that $\nu_p(Z)\geq 3\nu_p(X)$. We assume $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ (which can always be achieved by an appropriate change of variables in the Weierstrass equation), so that $\nu_p(a),\nu_p(b)\geq 0$. We distinguish two cases:

- Suppose first that $\nu_p(Z)<\nu_p(X)$. Then,
  $$\nu_p(Z)=\nu_p(X^3+aXZ^2+bZ^3)\geq \min\{\nu_p(X^3),\nu_p(aXZ^2),\nu_p(bZ^3)\}\geq \min\{3\nu_p(X),\nu_p(a)+\nu_p(X)+2\nu_p(Z),\nu_p(b)+3\nu_p(Z)\}\geq 3\nu_p(Z).$$
  Thus, $\nu_p(Z)\geq 3\nu_p(Z)$ and so $\nu_p(Z)\leq 0$. However, $Z=z/y$ and $[x,y,z]$ is in the kernel of reduction, which means $\nu_p(z/y)>0$, a contradiction.
- Hence, we must have $\nu_p(Z)\geq \nu_p(X)$. Then,
  $$\nu_p(Z)=\nu_p(X^3+aXZ^2+bZ^3)\geq \min\{\nu_p(X^3),\nu_p(aXZ^2),\nu_p(bZ^3)\}\geq \min\{3\nu_p(X),\nu_p(a)+\nu_p(X)+2\nu_p(Z),\nu_p(b)+3\nu_p(Z)\}\geq 3\nu_p(X)\geq 3n,$$
  as desired.

Comment: How do you know that $3 \nu_p(X) \leq \nu_p(aXZ^2), \nu_p(bZ^3)$?

Comment: Also, once you know this, how do you continue?

Comment: Consider two cases, $\nu_p(X)\geq \nu_p(Z)$ and $\nu_p(X)\leq \nu_p(Z)$. One should give you a contradiction, and the other one what you desire.

Comment: I really don't see it. I'll let it rest and get back to you tomorrow. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: found it! But I used that $\nu_p(a) = \nu_p(b) =0$, but I'm not entirely certain why that holds..

Comment: You don't need to assume that. I'll update my answer later with more details.

Comment: Done. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.